# Importing CSV file with GlobalIDs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, global-id

I have a csv file which only contains GlobalIDs, no addresses, no lat/long.

Can I import it into QGIS to create a new layer?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: What do "GlobalIDs" look like? Where do they come from?